# Display data on detail page using useContext

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to display data on my detail page using context and route. here is my code:

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { ProductContext } from "../contexts/ProductContext";

export const ProductDetail = (route) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState("");
  const { product } = useContext(ProductContext);
  const currentProductId = route.match.params.id;

  useEffect(() => {
    const productId = currentProductId;
    const selectedProduct = product[0].products.find((item) => item.id === productId);

    setData(selectedProduct);

    console.log(product[0].products);
    console.log("id", productId);
    console.log("selected product:", selectedProduct);

    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {data.id}
      <Link to="/">Back</Link>
    </>
  );
};

export default ProductDetail;
```

`product[0].products` returns correct data:

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: 1, image: "./images/h95.jpg", title: "H95", …}
1: {id: 2, image: "./images/e8.jpg", title: "E8", …}
2: {id: 3, image: "./images/h4.jpg", title: "H4", …}
length: 3
```

`productId` returns correct id but `selectedProduct` returns undefined. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: `const ProductDetail = (route)` here, `route` is not the `route`, it is `props` object. Do you mean `const ProductDetail = ({ route })` Is this a typo? Because you said "`productId` returns correct id".

Comment: no. if I do ({ route }) ill get: TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined

Comment: Ok, so you are just naming `props` as `route`. This confused me, sorry. Then just check the `productId`. What do you see when you log it?

Comment: this is the path: `http://localhost:3000/detail/2` ...and logged `productId` is 2 ...the `selectedProduct` part for some reason doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

aaand I just realized my own stupid mistake...it should be `parseInt(productId)` instead of `productId`. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about that but first I want to see what is the output. I'm glad that you solved it.